# Learning Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am learning spark streaming using the book "Learning spark Streaming". In the book i found the following on a section talking about ***Dstream, RDD, block/partition.***

> Finally, one important point that is glossed over in this schema is that the Receiver interface also has the option of connecting to a data source that delivers a collection (think Array) of data pieces. This is particularly relevant in some de-serialization uses, for example. In this case, the Receiver does not go through a block interval wait to deal with the segmentation of data into partitions, but instead considers the whole collection reflects the segmentation of the data into blocks, and creates one block for each element of the collection. This operation is demanding on the part of the Producer of data, since it requires it to be producing blocks at the ratio of the block interval to batch interval to function reliably (delivering the correct number of blocks on every batch). But some have found it can provide superior performance, provided an implementation that is able to quickly make many blocks available for serialization.

I have been banging my head around and can't simply understand what the Author is talking about, although i feel like i should understand it. Can someone give me some pointers on that ?

Answer (score 1):

Disclosure: I'm co-author of the book.

What we want to express there is that the custom receiver API has 2 working modes: one where the producing side delivers one-message-at-time and the other where the receiver may deliver many messages at once (bulk).

- In the one-message-at-time mode, Spark is responsible of buffering and collecting the data into blocks for further processing.
- In the bulk mode, the burden of buffering and grouping is on the producing side, but it might be more efficient in some scenarios.

This is reflected in the API:

```
def store(dataBuffer: ArrayBuffer[T]): Unit
    Store an ArrayBuffer of received data as a data block into Spark's memory.

def store(dataItem: T): Unit
    Store a single item of received data to Spark's memory.
```

I agree with you that the paragraph is convoluted and might not convey the message as clear as we would like. I'll take care of improving it.

Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Thank u, i understand now. however could clarify what is meant by: "This is particularly relevant in some de-serialization uses" could u give an e.g.